# Is it possbile to add custom throtlling policy in wso2 apim choreo

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-choreo

Could you please if is possible to add **custom throttling policy ** in wso2 apim chero Saas version?

I tired below steps given by chatgpt but the below steps are not good.

===================================================================================
Log in to the WSO2 Choreo Console using your admin credentials.

Click on the "Throttling Policies" option from the main menu.

Click on the "Add" button to create a new throttling policy.

Select the "Custom" option to create a custom throttling policy.

Enter a name and description for the new policy.

Choose the policy level (API or resource) that you want the policy to apply to.

Define the conditions that will trigger the policy, such as source IP address, HTTP method, or other criteria.

Define the limits for the policy, such as the maximum number of requests or bandwidth usage.

Click "Save" to create the custom throttling policy.

Once you have created the policy, you can apply it to your APIs or resources by selecting it from the list of available policies on the "Throttling" page.

In summary, creating a custom throttling policy in the latest version of WSO2 Choreo is a straightforward process that involves defining the policy attributes and limits, and then applying the policy to the relevant APIs or resources. By creating custom throttling policies, you can ensure that your APIs are protected from excessive usage and provide a better experience to your API consumers.

Comment: Can you raise this question in Choreo discord channel for better visiblity?

Answer (score 0):

Choreo allows you to implement an API policy as a Ballerina project and attach it to an API proxy component.

You can follow [this documentation](https://wso2.com/choreo/docs/api-management/api-policies/#implement-an-api-a-policy) to create a custom policy in Choreo.